Docker: how to limit the port of a docker
I have a Docker container that I want to restrict so that it can only access a single port on my host, say the port 1234. I want to ensure that the container cannot access any other IP addresses or ports other than 1234 on the host. How can I achieve this?

iptables can be set to block traffic coming from your docker interface, and then you can specify ports to allow.
rob@jinn:~$ docker run -it --rm nicolaka/netshoot nmap -Pn 10.0.0.10
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-11-28 10:02 UTC
Nmap scan report for jinn.lan (10.0.0.10)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed tcp ports (reset)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
rob@jinn:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
rob@jinn:~$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i docker0 -j DROP
rob@jinn:~$ docker run -it --rm nicolaka/netshoot nmap -Pn 10.0.0.10
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-11-28 10:02 UTC
Nmap scan report for jinn.lan (10.0.0.10)
Host is up (0.000040s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.58 seconds

